# jquery large data insertion into DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In js I am calling server via ajax and server is returning me processed data that I should insert into the dom.

```
$.fn.loadChildren = function() {
  var $li = $(this);

  ajaxQueue.add({
    url:     "myUrl.to",
    data:    "mydata",
    success: function(data) {

      $li.find("ul").html(data);
      ....
```

Issue is that data could be quite huge string and in that case in FF I am getting error msg 
"A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding..."

I tried  using replaceWith instead of html but I still have the same problem.

I know there is a limitation for DOM insertion in every browser but I want to know is there anything else in jQuery optimization that I could try.

Thanks

Comment: How big is `data`?  Seems like it would have to be pretty huge, or there are a lot of `ul` being found

Comment: you could get the data in chunks.  Just specify a start and end for you ajax calls and server side and then do a callback to get the next chunk after you've finished with the current chunk

Comment: there is only one ul. I logged data.length and result is 2011684 characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Narrow down the selector possibly?

```
$("#myul").html(data);
```

Try chunking the data. Something like this should help improve performance a bit.

```
var chunks = [];
var counter = 0;

chunks = breakApartDataIntoChunks(data);

setTimeout(function() { processChunk(chunks, counter); }, 0);

function processChunk(chunks, counter) {
    if (counter < chunks.length) {
        // insert this chunk into dom here
        $li.find("ul").append(chunks[counter]);
        counter++;
        setTimeout(function() { processChunk(chunks, counter); }, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: hm I dont quite understand you code. should nI chunk the data in the done part of the ajax? how is data exactly inserted in your exemple?

Comment: I would take your current response and break it apart into chunks then process it as shown above. So not making multiple request rather taking the single request break it into an array of chunks then send it into the `processChunks()` method.

Comment: Hi Gabe, thanks for your response. I was testing your approach, only problem is that the code that follows the whole process should be executed after the process of chunking/inserting finishes. If i add console.log("1") after your setTimeout(function() { processChunk(chunks, counter); }, 0); this log will be executed before all of the inserting is done! is t here a way to control this ?

Comment: also i think that html() will not work since every new chunk will replace the existing. append is better but if original data was chunked in the comment string, then it will break.

Comment: I accepted you answer since it helped improve the performance a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that what you return is not a huge piece of Html, but many elements, like a list or a table, what you could do is instead of returning html, return a JSON array, with those elements, and insert them one by one, something like this:

```
//response = ['<div>One Element</div>', '</div>Another Elmenet</div>']
for(var i = 0; i < response.lenght; i++) {
     $('ul#myElement').append($('<li>').html(response[i]));
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks for the response, i was searching for fast solution in the js but your solution should also work.